# Commentary on Rashi

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi

Can can someone recommend a commentary on Rashi?

I am looking for a commentary that is a) Hebrew b) contains the text of the Humash and preferably Onkelos c) a clear explanation of Rashi's commentary that helps one to develop a stronger understanding of Rashi, his commentary, and his approach to exegesis d) clear with nice print

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a deeper understanding of Rashi then sam's answer is great. If you are looking for a basic understanding to help understand the Rashi as it is I would recommend Rashi kpshuto

[image: רש"י כפשוטו]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. This is much more along the lines of what I'm looking for, just a basic understanding of Rashi. Do you happen to know how this Rashi K'Pshuto compares to Oz VeHadar's Humash Rashi? https://ozvehadar.us/Chumash-Rashi-Hamevuar/

Comment: The difference is Rashi K'pshuto is easier to read, it helps the words of Rashi flow, they focus on understanding Rashi. the Oz Vhudar version is more telling you how the meforshim explains Rash rather then helping understand the words of Rashi

Comment: Perfect, that helps a lot. Thank you!

Comment: This is the exact same one you showed, right? https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/pshuto-shel-mikrarashi-kipshuto-5-volume-set/28776?Style=Full%20Size%20Hardcover

Comment: Will change the picture in a minute... this is the one I meant https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/rashi-kipshuto-set/28777 I never used the one from your link

Comment: Excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Chumash that contains 11 meforshim on Rashi .

Pictures of set:

[image]

[image]